How to auto-complete a git command that is not the first one in a git alias?
I have this alias in my .gitconfig file
auto-stash-switch = "!f(){ git stash && git switch \"$1\"; };f"

This should help me when I need to switch to another branch but my working directory is not clean.
It is working but the auto-completion (TAB) is like linked to the stash command, meaning that if I type:
what I see is:
$ git auto-stash-switch [TAB]
apply branch clear create ... push show

that are the commands associated to git stash when you TAB. I would like to transfer this auto-completion to the git switch command. I have tried the null command like in the following
auto-stash-switch = "!f(){ git stash && : git switch \"$1\"; };f"

but it still takes the auto-completion of the stash.
Any suggestions for this?
Thanks

Content in code segments should only be literal code. Bolding and other formatting does not work there.

You can use git autocompletion utility functions to set autocompletion for your custom alias.
In bash:
# add this to your .bashrc:
__git_complete auto-stash-switch _git_switch

and git auto-stash-switch will have the same completion as git switch
(you may test this in your current shell by just running that function once, and see if the autocompletion works as you expect)

Unfortunately I get the same result.
